# Javascript on page load code make it reload chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, pageload

I'm bulding a chrome extension.

I want to execute a function on page load:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
      var tabUrl =  tab.url ;
      //code ...
  }
});
```

This way it takes a lot of time to load, and after it finish loading it starts another load. Which is another good way to do it ?

Comment: just try `window.onload = function() { /* your code */ };` or `(function(){ /* your code */ }());`

Comment: What function are you wanting to call after the page has loaded? Depending on what it is, you might want to use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Comment: I have added my js file in content script

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where your code is, you could use the following two ways: (Saying your logic is `func()`

1. Content Scripts. If your code is in content scripts, you could directly call `func` without listen to any event. Since by default (without setting `run_at`)  the `run_at` would be `document_idle`, which means you scripts will be loaded after `window.onload` event fires. Or if you want, you could set `run_at: document_start`, then listen to `window.onload` event.
2. Background page. If you want to monitor current page in background page, you could listen to [webNavigation.onCompleted](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCompleted) event, it fires when a document, including the resources it refers to, is completely loaded and initialized.